# Change default working directory in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to change the default Working directory in Qt Creator to specified path? 
Or is it possible to set Working directory in .pro file?

PS: I know about QDir::setCurrent, but searching for other ways

Comment: I think it can be done in the project configuration pane, but I haven't worked with QtCreator for some time now.

Answer (score 12):

go to the projects tab and look in "build and run" for the run tab in the kit you are using

you will see the option there under "run"

Comment: It will change Working directory for the only one project, and I want to change the default Working directory, so when I open new project the Working directory be already what I want

Comment: Those settings are persistent for any given project. I fail to see the issue unless you're creating dozens of projects...

Comment: Maybe the OP is frustrated with having to change the settings for each and every project? This is a perfectly valid question to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but, as there is no accepted answer and I recently found this question while looking:

Tools > Options > Build & Run > General > enter the desired Projects Directory location in the provided text box, or use Browse to locate it.

Note: assuming Qt Creator 4.3.1 based on Qt 5.9.1, Linux x86-64

Qt Creator Online Doc: [**Specifying Run Settings**](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html)

[image: Snapshot from doc.]