# Can't open a .txt file from the directory of the project

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm using QT creator IDE.

I need to open a .txt file which is already in my projects folder. I don't want to specify a directory like "C/NewFolder/..." since I want my programm to run in other computers as well (where they might not have a "NewFolder". This is my code:

```
std::ifstream bibliothekFile;       
bibliothekFile.open("Library.txt"); // the txt file is named Library

if (bibliothekFile.is_open()) 
{
   // some code 
}
else
{
   std::cout << "error";
}
```

I always get the "error", but when I specify the directory where my project and Library file is saved, then the code runs without a problem.

Comment: You're using Qt Creator. Open a File Dialog and you'll see that the current working directory isn't where you think it is. It's going to be in ../buildFOO-debug (or some such weird path), then buried deep down inside there. It's NOT where you think it is.

Comment: okey... could you maybe  provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put Library.txt in same dir where your binary is (program that you compile and run).

Comment: the Library.txt file is already in the  directory where my programm is saved. (i coppied it to the Projects folder)

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs, and Qt Creator is in the list, don't use the project home directory as the current working directory when the program runs. This is fairly common.

This answer tells you how you can manage that.

[Change default working directory in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757447/change-default-working-directory-in-qt-creator)

If you're building a GUI app, though, then who knows where the working directory will be when you install and run it? So you may need to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the Library.txt file in the project folder, where the .exe of my project is. It was in C/documents.
You have to add it in the debug folder. (if it didnt work then add it in the parent folder of debug)