# How to write to file in C++

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I've tried to write to file in C++ on a mac in different ways and I can't.
I've used:

```
int bestScore = 3;
QFile data("bestScore.txt");
data.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream out(&data);
out << bestScore;
data.close();
```

```
int bestScore = 3;
FILE *out_file = fopen("bestScore.txt", "w");
if (out_file == NULL) 
{   
  qDebug() << "File not open";
}
fprintf(out_file, "%d", bestScore);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you run the programs? Are you sure you're looking in the program's working directory? What if you try an absolute path instead of just the filename?

Comment: Thanks, I've not thought about giving the whole path, but is there a way to make it work if I change the direction and with that file in the same folder as the program?

Comment: A program's working directory is not necessarily as the directory containing the executable. Are you running the program from a shell, or from an IDE? From a shell these ought to work like you expect and create a file in your current directory. An IDE might be using a working directory you didn't expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like the program to work in an executable not from an IDE or shell and thats how I'm running it, but I'm building it in Qt Creator.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're facing? Is the example code that you provide *crashing*, does it maybe *not compile*, or you just cannot *find the file it has written*? Or something completely else? My crystal ball is a little hazy today ;)

Comment: FYI: [Change default working directory in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519640/7478597) or (even better) the Qt Creator online doc.: [Specifying Run Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html)

Comment: ***Can anyone help?*** No, because we don't know what we can help with. Maybe your problem is related to deployment of a Qt application and has nothing to do with writing a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478075/creating-files-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you need to include the `fstream` standard library header.
Second, you declare the name of the file as a variable.
You need to open it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

**If this doesn't work try to give the exact location of the file example**

```
myfile.open("/Library/Application/randomfilename/example.txt");
```